# SELECT rows from a table that don't have related entries in a second table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

That's my first day in SQL using PostgreSQL 9.4 and I'm lost with some things. I think that I'm close but not enough:

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE DOCTOR (
    Doc_Number INTEGER,
    Name    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Specialty   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Address VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    City    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Phone   VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Salary  DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
    DNI     VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE
    CONSTRAINT pk_Doctor PRIMARY KEY (Doc_Number)
  );

CREATE TABLE VISIT (
    Doc_Number    INTEGER,
    Pat_Number    INTEGER,
    Visit_Date    DATE,
    Price           DECIMAL(7,2),
    CONSTRAINT Visit_pk PRIMARY KEY (Doc_Number, Pat_Number, Visit_Date),
    CONSTRAINT Visit_Doctor_fk FOREIGN KEY (Doc_Number) REFERENCES DOCTOR(Doc_Number),
    CONSTRAINT Visit_PATIENT_fk FOREIGN KEY (Pat_Number) REFERENCES PATIENT(Pat_Number)
  );
```

I need how to join these two queries into one:

```
SELECT d.City, d.Name
FROM DOCTOR d, VISIT v
WHERE d.Specialty = 'family and comunity' 
ORDER BY d.Name;

SELECT * FROM VISIT
WHERE DATE (Visit_Date)<'01/01/2012' 
            OR DATE(Visit_Date)>'31/12/2013';
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't work. I need the doctors of that specialty that didn't do any visit in 2012 and 2013.

```
SELECT City, Name
FROM DOCTOR d
WHERE d.Specialty = 'family and comunity' 
      AND NOT IN(SELECT *
        FROM VISIT 
        WHERE Visit_Date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' and '2013-12-31')
ORDER BY d.Name;
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: . . If you have three questions, you should probably ask them one at a time.

Comment: ok, thanks for your advice, the next time I'll do it this way

Comment: @alwayslearn: You can get it right *this* time. Just edit the question while you don't have answers, yet. And spawn two new question.

Comment: Please always provide your version of Postgres. And table definitions if the query depends on it (like in this case): what you get with `\d tbl` in psql. How are the tables `doctor` and `visit` connected? I assume you have a `doctor_id` in `visit`? You need a join condition.

Comment: ok I edit the post to insert the creation of tables to do more understandable, I don't need a join condition, only one query to obtain the name and city of the doctors with specialty 'family and comunity' that didn't do any visit in 2012 and 2013, ordered by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution, this is quite similar to your solutions, I post here to help another people with similar problems

```
SELECT City, Name
FROM DOCTOR d, VISIT v
WHERE d.Specialty = 'family and comunity' 
          AND not exists(SELECT *
          FROM visit v WHERE v.doc_number = d.doc_number
          AND v.visit_date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2013-12-31')      
GROUP BY name, city
ORDER BY d.Name;
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: You can do `SELECT DISTINCT city, name` instead of adding `GROUP BY` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT d.name, d.city
FROM   doctor     d
LEFT   JOIN visit v ON v.doc_number = d.doc_number
                   AND v.visit_date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'
WHERE  d.specialty = 'family and community'  -- or 'family and comunity'?
AND    v.doc_number IS NULL
ORDER  BY d.name;
```

- As commented you need a join condition. How are visits connected to doctors? Typically, you would have a `visit.doctor_id` referencing `doctor.doctor_id`.
- Using `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` to rule out doctors who have visits in said period. This is one of several possible techniques:

  - [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)
- Dates must be greater than the lower bound **`AND`** smaller than the upper bound. <strike>`OR`</strike> would be wrong here.
- It's better to use ISO 8601 date format which is unambiguous regardless of your locale.

  - [field value between date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983146/field-value-between-date-range/11173651#11173651)

Comment: Hi, about the first point, yes I have a Doc_Number in both tables, about the dates, yes, I need the doctors who DON'T have visits in this period, I tried your code but it returns and empty table and I'm sure that there are 2 doctors that don't have visits in this period.

Comment: @alwayslearn: Trust me, the query is right. Maybe those doctors have another specialty or you really spelled "family and community" with just one "m"?

Comment: I copied and pasted the specialty, and I check in my insertions one doctor that don't have visits in this period and also don't have another specialty, this should be appear in the query but not, I don't doubt about your code but I don't understand what happens.

Comment: @alwayslearn: If you copied and pasted, then it is like I suspected, and `'family and comunity' ` is not a typo. I have `'family and community'` in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to the `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE NULL` construct is the plain `WHERE NOT EXISTS(...)` anti-join. [It is completely equivalent to erwin's query]

```
SELECT d.name, d.city
FROM   doctor  d
WHERE  d.specialty = 'family and community'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 13
    FROM visit v WHERE v.doc_number = d.doc_number
                   AND v.visit_date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'
    )
ORDER  BY d.name;
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this code by myself before  and I obtain the same empty table as the previous code by Erwin

Comment: As I said: they are equivalent. (and both correct). Maybe your table or data are different from what you wrote in your question?

Comment: Sorry I can't find any errors in my construction tables and my insertions are aparently correct, thanks for your help, I'll keep trying to find what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there... Instead of

```
SELECT City, Name
FROM DOCTOR d
WHERE d.Specialty = 'family and comunity' 
      AND NOT IN(SELECT *
        FROM VISIT 
        WHERE Visit_Date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' and '2013-12-31')
ORDER BY d.Name;
```

try

```
SELECT City, Name
FROM DOCTOR d
WHERE d.Specialty = 'family and comunity' 
      AND doc_number NOT IN(SELECT doc_number -- or SELECT DISTINCT doc number - to get fewer rows from the subquery
        FROM VISIT 
        WHERE Visit_Date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' and '2013-12-31')
ORDER BY d.Name;
```

Just in case - table/column names are case-insensitive by default in Postgres. If you want them case sensitive - you have to write them in "" .

Comment: Hi @murison as the same of the other times i get an empty table with your code, I turn mad trying to understand what's wrong with the code. But thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe that's the way it is in your data? Place some example data and desired output.